Is it possible to read user input with no extra variables?
I want to grep an IP address inside Nginx configuration files.
I want to input the IP address with the read command, but I don't want to store input in an additional variable.
So I want something like:
grep -ir $(read) /etc/nginx/

What's the correct way to use read inside argument?

Could you explain what context you would use this in? Why would you ever want to use read there instead of passing the IP as an argument, ensuring the command can be repeated and any typos caught and corrected? And why do you want to avoid a variable anyway?

Note that if the purpose is to avoid polluting the scope, whatever you declare in a subshell, such as in the example, dies with the subshell; for functions, you may use let.

Yes, you can do it without explicitly setting a variable. From help read (emphasis mine):

$ help read read: read [-ers] [-a array] [-d delim] [-i text] [-n
nchars] [-N nchars] [-p prompt] [-t timeout] [-u fd] [name ...]
Read a line from the standard input and split it into fields.
Reads a single line from the standard input, or from file descriptor FD
if the -u option is supplied.  The line is split into fields as with word
splitting, and the first word is assigned to the first NAME, the second
word to the second NAME, and so on, with any leftover words assigned to
the last NAME.  Only the characters found in $IFS are recognized as word
delimiters. By default, the backslash character escapes delimiter characters
and newline.
If no NAMEs are supplied, the line read is stored in the REPLY variable.

You don't need to give a variable, you can use the $REPLY one. Of course that still is a variable, but I can't think of any reason to avoid that anyway. I mean, this is a shell script, not C, there's no point in that level of optimization or you would be using a proper programming language.
So you could do something like:
ip_grep(){ read && grep -FR -w -e "$REPLY" /etc/nginx/; }

You would then run ip_grep, it would prompt for input and run the grep. There really is no point to that though. Why not use the simpler:
ip_grep(){ grep -FR -w -e "$@" /etc/nginx/; }

Now, you can just run ip_grep 1.2.3.4 and it would grep for that IP. If you give more context for why you want this, I can update the answer.

Thank you for your answer, but I don't want multi-action via ; line.
I've got the solution at another resource and will post as separate answer here.

@palmasd1 that isn't a solution to what your question asked for since it doesn't use read. And there is still no benefit in complicating the command like that instead of just passing the IP to grep on launch or, if you don't want to type it out, using an alias or a function as I show here.

Hm. I re-read all discussion here and realized that my answer was off-topic. The problem - at all - I haven't formulated the goal for myself, and then started to search any solution. Thank you for sharing.
